# Scrape data from reduced table

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Using Beautiful Soup and isolating my web source data inside a 'p' tag, I managed to retrieve the data that I need. Now, I'd like to iterate over the remaining data inside the variable 'table' (over each row and each cell) to scrape the data into a list. Can anyone help me how to achieve this? I've read several other posts but was not able to apply this to my specific issue... Thanks.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
url = "http://www.gks.ru/bgd/free/B00_25/IssWWW.exe/Stg/d000/000715.HTM"
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read(), 'html.parser')
table=soup.findAll('p',text=True)
print(table)
```

Comment: What do you want your output to look like?

Comment: Are you using `Chicken` or `BeefStock`?

Comment: [a]Triptych: I'd like to look it as the original table (http://www.gks.ru/bgd/free/B00_25/IssWWW.exe/Stg/d000/000715.HTM)

[a]wogsland: so far, none of the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to get the per-month price data, you would need to find all `tr` elements inside a `table` and skip the first 3 (header rows). Note that, `html.parser` did not work for me, but `lxml` did (see [Differences between parsers](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers)):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')  # requires 'lxml' to be installed

table = soup.find("center").find("table")
for row in table.find_all("tr")[3:]:
    cells = [cell.get_text(strip=True) for cell in row.find_all("td")]
    print(cells)
```

Prints:

```
['January', '469,4', '15,0', '3,9']
['February', '479,8', '16,7', '2,2']
['March', '485,6', '16,9', '1,2']
['April', '487,8', '16,4', '0,5']
['May', '489,5', '15,8', '0,4']
['June', '490,5', '15,3', '0,2']
['July', '494,4', '15,6', '0,8']
['August', '496,1', '15,8', '0,4']
['September', '499,0', '15,7', '0,6']
['October', '502,7', '15,6', '0,7']
['November', '506,4', '15,0', '0,8']
['December', '', '', '']
```

Comment: This looks fantastic, thanks alecxe. However, when using your code, I'm getting the following error: AttributeError                            Traceback 

----> 9 table = soup.find("center").find("table")

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'

Comment: @mr_bungles okay, thanks, are you using `lxml` as a parser (as in the answer)?

Comment: yes, as per "import lxml" and "soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')"

Comment: @mr_bungles okay, one more check, what `beautifulsoup` version are you using? (try updating it to the latest version `pip install beautifulsoup4 --upgrade`)

Comment: it's version 4.4.1 (was already up-to-date), in combination with python 2.7.

Comment: @mr_bungles okay, what else can be different..try upgrading `lxml` too - I also have the latest installed.

Comment: Very strange - that's also up-to-date... do you also use python 2.7? In my original version of the code, if I exchange the html parser with the lxml parser, I also do not get any results anymore...

Comment: @mr_bungles yeah, it works for me in both Python 2.7 and Python 3.5. Strange.

Comment: @mr_bungles just a guess, remove the "pyc" file located right near your script and run the script again.

Comment: Unfortunately, that also didn't solve the problem. In my original code, the html parsers gives me already filtered results. Is there a way to iterate through those results in order to isolate the final desired data?

Comment: @mr_bungles don'f forget to accept the answer if it helped. Also, look through your previous questions and accept answers. Thanks.